# How to reset the vue-tel-input input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-tel-input

I have the following code:

`<vue-tel-input ref="telinput" v-model="phone" @input="updatePhone"></vue-tel-input>`

and then:

```
const updatePhone = (event, p) => {
    if (event.constructor.name === "InputEvent") {
        return;
    }
    if (p !== undefined && p.valid) {
        phone.value = p.nationalNumber
        valid.value = true
    } else {
        valid.value = false
        phone.value = ""
    }
}

const addPhone = () => {
    store.mailing.tokens.unshift([
        phone.value,
        variable.value
    ])
    valid.value = false
    phone.value = ""
    window.Toast.fire({
        title: 'Contato adicionado com sucesso!',
        icon: 'success'
    });
}
```

But the phone variable is never changed by the `v-model` and when I call the `addPhone` method the input still showing the phone typed by the user.

Comment: what is the point of `if (event.constructor.name === "InputEvent") { return; }`? when/how do you call `addPhone`

Comment: Try  `phone.value = { ...phone }`  after you update `phone.value`. I guess vue is not detecting the change, so re-assigning the object to the variable might help.

Comment: @JaromandaX InputEvent means that the user is typing the phone. If it is the last digit it will call two times the function, one with InputEvent and another one. I call the add phone when user clicks on a button.

Comment: @SyncroIT where exactly should I put this? Inside the if statement?

Comment: `one with InputEvent and another one` why would `@input="updatePhone"` call `updatePhone` with an event other than `InputEvent` - what "other one" are you getting?

Comment: also, what do you believe the value of `p` should be in `const updatePhone = (event, p) => {` - is there some OTHER code calling `updatePhone` you've forgotten to include in the question? Frankly, unless I'm missing something, I see no reason to have `@input="updatePhone"` since `updatePhone` doesn't actually do anything with `input` events

Comment: @JaromandaX I changed to `console.log(event)` this is what I received when typed 14 in the input: [image](https://i.imgur.com/0mGGT8z.png)

Comment: Hello @JaromandaX, I hadn't seen your last response. I'm using the method because the v-model doesn't update the value entered in the variable.